# Cisco UCS compatibility with FC-AL storage array

Tags: cisco, storage, storage-area-network, fibre-channel, cisco-ucs

We have a Xiotech RS-1602-FC-SBD storrage array that I am testing to see if it is of any use. We have a Cisco UCS Chassis with blade servers and a Fabric Interconnect 6120XP.

The storage array operates in FC-AL (Arbitrated Loop), but I haven't found a way to configure the Fabric Interconnect in any way that the blade servers can see the storage. I searched for Cisco UCS FC-AL support and found absolutely nothing. The company that manufactures the storage array is long gone and only left a manual behind. The manual only has information about the configuration of the array, but from what I can see the storage array doesn't have any Fibre Channel network configuration options. Just some physical switches on the back to configure them. The manual of the storage array can be found here: https://www.manualslib.com/products/Xyratex-Rs-1602-Fc-Sbd-3638481.html

My actual question is: Can you configure FC-AL storage arrays with a Cisco Fabric Interconnect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can tell you definitively that the Nexus 5K line (...which is the parent product to that version of the FI) won't natively connect FC-AL and thus it's reasonable to expect that the native FI won't support it either.

I have several similar arrays and ended up just putting a small MDS switch in between the FI and the arrays.  This also allows for better control of channels, HA, zoning, etc and is more consistent with the design guidance for UCS (which tends to frown on direct connecting arrays).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. We'll see what we can do and I'll update this post later